# HttpServer with flutter windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, firewall, httpserver

I have a flutter windows HttpServer like this

```
  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 2345);
  print('Listening on ${server.port}');
  server.listen((req) {
    req.response
      ..write('request received successfully')
      ..close();
  });
```

when trying to run it on a windows flutter app it only works for local connections from the windows machine itself.
But when trying to access it from an android device for example from the same local network it doesn't work.

---

I did some search and found out that I must add a firewall inbound rule for my app to be able to listen for outside connections
I did it manually from the **Windows Defender Firewall** and it worked.

I need to make it programmatically from my flutter code.
then tried this code

```
   final processResult = Process.runSync(
  'netsh',
  [
    'advfirewall',
    'firewall',
    'add',
    'rule',
    'name="My App Rule Name"',
    'action=allow',
    'program="${Platform.resolvedExecutable}"',
    'dir=in',
    'protocol=tcp',
  ],
);
```

but I am getting this result

```
  A specified value is not valid.

  Usage: add rule name=<string>
  dir=in|out
  action=allow|block|bypass
  [program=<program path>]
  [service=<service short name>|any]
  [description=<string>]
  [enable=yes|no (default=yes)]
  [profile=public|private|domain|any[,...]]
  [localip=any|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
  [remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|
     <IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
  [localport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|RPC|RPC-EPMap|IPHTTPS|any (default=any)]
  [remoteport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|any (default=any)]
  [protocol=0-255|icmpv4|icmpv6|icmpv4:type,code|icmpv6:type,code|
     tcp|udp|any (default=any)]
  [interfacetype=wireless|lan|ras|any]
  [rmtcomputergrp=<SDDL string>]
  [rmtusrgrp=<SDDL string>]
  [edge=yes|deferapp|deferuser|no (default=no)]
  [security=authenticate|authenc|authdynenc|authnoencap|notrequired 
     (default=notrequired)]

  Remarks:

  - Add a new inbound or outbound rule to the firewall policy.
  - Rule name should be unique and cannot be "all".
  - If a remote computer or user group is specified, security must be
    authenticate, authenc, authdynenc, or authnoencap.
  - Setting security to authdynenc allows systems to dynamically
    negotiate the use of encryption for traffic that matches
    a given Windows Defender Firewall rule. Encryption is negotiated based on
    existing connection security rule properties. This option
    enables the ability of a machine to accept the first TCP
    or UDP packet of an inbound IPsec connection as long as
    it is secured, but not encrypted, using IPsec.
    Once the first packet is processed, the server will
    re-negotiate the connection and upgrade it so that
    all subsequent communications are fully encrypted.
  - If action=bypass, the remote computer group must be specified when dir=in.
  - If service=any, the rule applies only to services.
  - ICMP type or code can be "any".
  - Edge can only be specified for inbound rules.
  - AuthEnc and authnoencap cannot be used together.
  - Authdynenc is valid only when dir=in.
  - When authnoencap is set, the security=authenticate option becomes an
    optional parameter.

  Examples:

  Add an inbound rule with no encapsulation security for browser.exe:
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="allow browser"
  dir=in program="c:\programfiles\browser\browser.exe"
  security=authnoencap action=allow

  Add an outbound rule for port 80:
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="allow80"
  protocol=TCP dir=out localport=80 action=block

  Add an inbound rule requiring security and encryption
  for TCP port 80 traffic:
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule
  name="Require Encryption for Inbound TCP/80"
  protocol=TCP dir=in localport=80 security=authdynenc
  action=allow

  Add an inbound rule for browser.exe and require security
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="allow browser"
  dir=in program="c:\program files\browser\browser.exe"
  security=authenticate action=allow

  Add an authenticated firewall bypass rule for group
  acmedomain\scanners identified by a SDDL string:
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="allow scanners"
  dir=in rmtcomputergrp=<SDDL string> action=bypass
  security=authenticate

  Add an outbound allow rule for local ports 5000-5010 for udp-
  Add rule name="Allow port range" dir=out protocol=udp localport=5000-5010 action=allow
```

And the problem not solved!

maybe I need to ask for a firewall permission to open a port but I don't know how

Comment: Bind it to address "0.0.0.0" like so: HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind("0.0.0.0", 2345);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a .bat script with the following

```
@echo off

set programPath=%1

set ruleName="Put Your Rule Name Here"

echo %date% %time%: Starting script with arguments %* >>C:\log.log

netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=%ruleName% >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Rule "%ruleName%" already exists. Exiting...
  echo %date% %time%: Rule "%ruleName%" already exists. Exiting... >>C:\log.log
  exit /b
)

echo Rule "%ruleName%" not found. Adding...
echo %date% %time%: Rule "%ruleName%" not found. Adding... >>C:\log.log

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%ruleName% action=allow enable=yes dir=in profile=domain,private,public localip=any remoteip=any protocol=any program=%programPath%
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%ruleName% action=allow enable=yes dir=out profile=domain,private,public localip=any remoteip=any protocol=any program=%programPath%

echo Rule "%ruleName%" added successfully.
echo %date% %time%: Rule "%ruleName%" added successfully. >>C:\log.log

exit /b
```

i saved the firewall_rule.bat and packaged it with my package using advanced installer for windows 
then made the script to run with the app installation to activate the rule with admin permission while the app installation.